# How to map JSON data to a class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I created a ES6 class by [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) and I want to map JSON data which is gotten from a server to the ES6 class. 
Is there anything common way to do that?

**User.js**

```
export default class User {
  constructor() {
    this.firstName;
    this.lastName;
    this.sex;
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import User from "./classes/User";

var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
console.log(data.firstname); //Bob
//now...just set data one by one?
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would merge the JSON object into `this` using `Object.assign`, as follows:

```
class User {
  firstName;
  lastName;
  sex;

  constructor(data) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}

var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
new User(data);
```

Comment: Your answer has me wondering (and hoping someone can give me a answer), but this *plain* constructor now no longer *defines* any `User` properties defeating the purpose of having a class definition. Could you perhaps add properties to your answer as an example?

Comment: Solution with `Object.assign` only works when there are no properties of some class type. If `User` had `address` we would need to call `this.address = new Address(data.address)` in `User` constructor.

Comment: This is naive solution, which doesn't take into consideration that attribute could be another class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-converter to map all JSON to a class.
it looks like following one:

```
import { property, toClass } from 'class-convert';

class UserModel {
  @property('i')
  id: number;

  @property()
  name: string;
}

const userRaw = {
  i: 1234,
  name: 'name',
};

// use toClass to convert plain object to class
const userModel = toClass(userRaw, UserModel);
// you will get a class, just like below one
{
  id: 1234,
  name: 'name',
}
```