# Classes in Webworkers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

What can and cannot be passed between a main thread JS and a webworker?

I have a JS class in a webworker and I would like to pass it to them main thread. What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to map a JSON object on to a class or do I need to create a special constructor for this?

```js
class HelloWorld{
    constructor(message){
        this.msg = message
    }
    getMessage(){
        debugger
        return this.msg;
    }
}
var a = new HelloWorld("hello WorlD")
postMessage(a)
```

The main thread reads this as `{msg:"hello WorlD"} strippign all member data and typeof data.

Comment: Did you try passing something and did it fail? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm

Comment: you cannot forward functions or similar dynamic objects to web workers. you can only provide an interface to the webworker to interact with such things in the main thread

Comment: Objects can be passed, but they are serialized along the way. Methods won't transfer of course.

Comment: You cannot pass functions to web workers, and that includes `class` constructors.

Comment: To be 100% clear, you mean you have a constructor function (with associated `prototype`) defined by `class` syntax and you want to pass that constructor function into the worker, correct? Or are you talking about passing an *instance* of the class created by calling it?

Comment: @apsillers - if that's the case, I'm questioning the use of a Worker in the first place. Why spawn a process just to load code that you pass back to the main? Makes no sense. OP - What exactly is the use case?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm building a voxel  game. I'd like to generate chunks, modify geometry, etc without blocking the main thread. I need to pass world data to the child thread and get voxel data back, or pass voxel data to the child thread and expect vertex/face data back. If I do that on the main thread, modifying the world would cause a full second (or longer) stop.

Comment: Great, so what does sending requests one way and data back have anything to do with passing a class to/from a worker?

Comment: your understanding of this is just a bit skewed. Your event listeners on your worker should be used to invoke methods in the worker (instances maybe) and then create a message containing the output from that method back to the main process. Passing a Class doesn't makes sense in any way. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think your understanding of my problem is a bit skewed. I want to pass an object that includes all the helper functionality (ie converting XYZ data to single dimensional array that I store chunk data in and other helper data). That makes perfect sense, but it sounds like this is a language limitation.
It sounds like this is my solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339675/how-to-map-json-data-to-a-class
As I mentioned in the original question, I'll need a special constructor.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer is the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).

For the case of sending class instances specifically:

1- Using `console.log(a)` to show it as a JS object shows something like:

```
{
  msg: "hello WorlD",
  __proto__: {
    constructor: ...,
    getMessage: ...,
    __proto__: {...}
  }
}
```

I.e., for a simple-enough class: one could *approximately* say that instance properties are normal object properties, and instance functions are properties on the `__proto__` property.

2- Following the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm): `msg` will be passed but the member function `getMessage` won't because "The prototype chain does not get walked and duplicated.".

3- If member functions were not part of the prototype chain but were defined directly as object prototypes, the whole passing of the object would've failed since `Function` objects can't be sent.
E.g., if you try: `a.getMessage2 = function() {return 7;}`, the whole object won't even be passed.

4-I don't know what you mean with `typeof` usage here but if you mean using `messageEvent.data instanceof HelloWorld`, then the problem here is that the main code/thread didn't include the web-worker file and thus has no knowledge of a `HelloWorld` definition.
To make them both see `HelloWorld`, you could either define the class in both files, or (1) define it in an external file (e.g., `hello-world.js`), (2) then import it in your main code/thread by adding `<script src="hello-world.js">` to your HTML, and (3) import it in your web-worker code by adding `importScripts('hello-world.js')` to the beginning of your web-worker file.

Disclaimer: I'm not very knowledgeable in classes. I'm using some probably-true assumptions on how classes instances will (and can) be treated as JS objects.